# php summarize variables with delimiter

Tags: php, html

Hello i have a basic question.
I get 4 variables from a html formular: $var1, $var2, $var3, $var4
I want to put them in one string $string but sometimes not all variables are set but i want a seperator like "/".

```
Example:
$var1 = "I"
$var2 = "was"
$var3 = "not"
$var4 = "here"
Example one: 
$string = $var1."/".$var2."/".$var3."/".$var4;
$string = I / was / not / here;
Example two:
$string = $var1."/".$var2."/".$var3."/".$var4;
$string = I / was /  / here;
```

Can someone help me with the extreme basic question?
Thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. What is wrong with the code you have? What isn't working?

Comment: in Example two i dont want the "/  /" i only want one "/". I need a script which counts how many variables i get from the html formular and than adds a "/" after the variable but not at the last one.

Comment: isset/empty exist, so you can write some nested if/else/elseif thing based on that, if you like. Of course you will have to address your individual variables individually as well then - that is one of the disadvantages of using "numbered" variable names. If you can modify the form this is coming from, then I would name the fields so that they automatically create an _array_ in PHP - then you can filter that for empty values, and then simply `implode` the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implode() on an array:

```
$all = [];
$all[] = $var1;
$all[] = $var2;
$all[] = $var4;

$string = implode('/',$all);
echo $string;
```

When a variable is not set, just do not put in the array.

Comment: If a variable is not set, you'll get a warning and invalid output: https://3v4l.org/YNQY8

Answer (score 1):

The natural tool for this kind of repetitive data is an array. It's also very hard to write code where variables may or may not exist.

To mitigate these design handicaps, you can normalise data into an array and work from there:

```
$var1 = "I";
$var2 = "was";
//$var3 = "not";
$var4 = "here";

$input = [
    $var1 ?? null,
    $var2 ?? null,
    $var3 ?? null,
    $var4 ?? null,
];
$nonEmptyInput = array_filter($input);
$output = implode(' / ', $nonEmptyInput);

var_dump($input, $nonEmptyInput, $output);
```

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "I"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "was"
  [2]=>
  NULL
  [3]=>
  string(4) "here"
}
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "I"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "was"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "here"
}
string(14) "I / was / here"
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/4bpn8)